# Create an action/animation equals Google Plus

Tags: java, android, android-animation

How do I create an action/animation equal to app google plus, when sliding down, hide the relative layout below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Here's a post by Roman Nurik: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt

Comment: QuickReturnView is called that. There is library, google it.